# How can I route power cables from my 2012 Kia Forte eco from the battery to the cabin?

Tags: electrical, kia, wiring

I have a 2012 Kia Forte sedan with "eco" package.  I'd like to mount my mobile amateur radio into the vehicle, however I'm having a hard time locating a grommet for passing power leads from the cabin into the engine compartment.

Does someone have a maintenance manual or other source that might be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet appears to be the firewall pass-through [behind the gas pedal](http://www.forteforums.com/forums/koup-audio-video-electronics/2263-where-pass-firewall-my-subwoofer-wire.html#post28625).  That should allow you to run behind the dash fairly directly.

Comment: Thanks, and 10 points subtracted for me as I'm a member of that very same forum.  My Google-Fu failed me.

Comment: @PeterGrace, I think you just summarized why this site is better than a whole pile of forum sites and a smattering of Google.  If you get a chance to take a picture of the grommet, put a link here and I'll include it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't say I know this with any certainty for this specific car, manufactures usually put this either below the steering column or behind the glove compartment.

Answer (score -1):

I'd think you'd be much better off piggybacking off of an existing circuit or going through the firewall with an existing wire bundle rather than drilling a new hole.  If you're determined though, make sure you don't drill through anything important.  I suppose you could seal around the wires with silicone.